# Problema al Llamar Prolog desde Php

Tags: php, wamp, prolog, odbc, swi-prolog

soy nuevo en este foro y un poco con el lenguaje de programación Prolog. Actualmente estoy trabajando en un proyecto basado en un Sistema Experto con interfaz web, utilizando para ello SWI-Prolog, con base en un aporte realizado en otro foro (http://www.forosdelweb.com/f18/aporte-llamar-prolog-desde-php-tener-sistema-experto-web-1101310/) que habla sobre como hacer una consulta a SWi-Prolog a través de codigo Php. Al seguir los pasos indicados en dicho foro pude realizar con éxito el llamado de SWI-Prolog desde Php, obteniendo el mensaje correspondiente en el navegador. Al irme luego directamente a hacer la consulta al archivo .pl que había hecho para mi proyecto, no logre obtener ninguna respuesta en pantalla. En mi archivo .pl (Funciona correctamente en la consola de SWI-Prolog) hago un llamado a una base de datos externa a través del odbc_connect, de donde obtengo ciertos datos que luego procedo a mostrar en el navegador. Al hacer ciertas pruebas, pude notar que al llamar a un archivo .pl desde Php y que la consulta requiera una conexión a una base de datos externa, esta no se realizara, por ende, al no cumplir con una de las reglas de la consulta, esta no devolverá ninguna respuesta. ¿Por que ocurre eso? ¿No es posible hacer la consulta a partir de Php a SWI-Prolog y este a su vez consulte una base de datos externa?

PD: Estoy utilizando Wampserver con servidor local.

A continuación se encuentra parte del código en Php y un código Prolog de prueba, al cual hago la consulta y si la conexión es realizada con éxito mostraría el "Hola" en pantalla (al probarlo en la consola de SWI-Prolog funciona correctamente, al igual que en la consola de Windows) .

index.php :

```
<?php 
if(!file_exists("Prueba2.pl")) die("No se puede localizar el archivo .pl, el 
directorio actual es: ".__DIR__);
$output = `swipl -s Prueba2.pl -g "abrir_conexion." -t halt.`;
print_r($output);
?>
```

Prueba2.pl :

```
abrir_conexion:-
odbc_connect('MSprolog',_,
             [user(root),
              password(''),
              alias(prolog),
              open(once)]),
              write('hola').
```

Comment: Si ejecutas `swipl -s Prueba2.pl -g "abrir_conexion." -t halt.` en la ubicación del fichero index.php ¿funciona?

Comment: Estimado, Publique todo su código, o al menos una mínima subparte de el donde podamos replicar el problema. Hay decenas de motivos por los cuales esto puede no funcionar y no vamos a jugar a las adivinanzas. En principio le comento que considero que conectar prolog a una base de datos, es un error de diseño, cada lenguaje es bueno para una cosa y prolog es bueno para resolver grandes pilas de recursion mediante programación funcional, estas usando una sofisticada llave cricket para clavar un clavo, lo ideal seria que prolog reciba una entrada con todos los datos que necesite para operar, los p

Comment: rocese y devuelva un resultado, y que sea quien llame a prolog, el encargado de recolectar esa información del origen que sea.

Por otro lado, el programa prolog no puede ser interactivo, es decir debe de funcionar como una caja negra, donde recibe una serie de entradas y devuelve una serie de salidas, sin interactuar con el usuario, ni con ficheros, ni con bbdd. En cuento a perfomance, el tiempo que se pierde realizando las invocaciones se compensa con el que se ahorra al no estar realizando estas tareas en prolog. En cuanto a funcionalidad, tener todos los archivos prolog programados de

Comment: esta manera, facilita la creación de pruebas unitarias, la integración con otras tecnologías y la depuración de fallos.

Quedo a la espera de su código fuente completo para una respuesta mas exacta.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, la tomare en cuenta. No publique el código completo porque sencillamente quería mostrarles un código de prueba rápido, y básicamente, ahí, es donde se encuentra la raíz de mi problema, la cual es no poder lograr la conexión a la BD haciendo un llamado de Prolog desde Php. Ahora, te tomo la palabra en cuanto a " estas usando una sofisticada llave cricket para clavar un clavo", lo mas sensato es que haga la consulta a la BD de manera externa y luego le envié los datos a Prolog. Simplemente quería probar la funcionalidades que dispone SWI-Prolog. Gracias.